# Unescape or html decode

Tags: php, twig

I'm using twig 1.12.2. My code generates some elements from code-behind, when rendering these with the latest version of twig they get html-encoded

```
{% for item in files_folders %}
<tr class="{{ cycle(['tr_odd', 'tr_even'], loop.index) }}">
    <td><img src="../templates/images/sharepoint/{{ item.ContentType }}.gif" border="0" alt=""/></td>
    <td>{{ item.Link }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Modified }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.FileSize }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.FileType }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This will output this

```
<tr class="tr_even">
    <td><img src="../templates/images/sharepoint/Document.gif" border="0" alt=""/></td>
    <td>&lt;a href=&#039;?download=/ddd.png&#039;&gt;ddd.png&lt;/a&gt;</td>
    <td>2013-03-04 17:47:38</td>
    <td>64.8 KB</td>
    <td>png</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_odd">
    <td><img src="../templates/images/sharepoint/Document.gif" border="0" alt=""/></td>
    <td>&lt;a href=&#039;?download=/asdasd.png&#039;&gt;asdasd.png&lt;/a&gt;</td>
    <td>2013-03-03 20:01:52</td>
    <td>66.04 KB</td>
    <td>png</td>
</tr>
```

When I debug and have a look at the data before it's sent to twig it is not escaped. I haven't found any alternative to {{ item.Link }} to render data as-is.

Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the `raw` filter to make twig render raw HTML.

```
{% autoescape %}
    {{ var|raw }} {# var won't be escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

[Source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html)

Comment: Good Answer +1 However, please include an example to ensure your answer stays relevant as links can `die` or become missing.

Comment: As always: Please be carefull when using |raw . If you raw user input, you open the gates for XSS.

Comment: I absolutely love this about twig - it makes sure some coder doesn't put unescaped variable content to output, unlike other template languages where e.g. `{{x}}` would do that which is harder to recognize against `{x}` in comparison with very explicit `|raw` :-)

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html

Answer (score 18):

You should be careful with using |raw. Saying that the data is safe, means you are trusting it 100%.

Personally I would suggest using a custom twig filter:

```
class CustomExtension extends \Twig_Extension 
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('unescape', array($this, 'unescape')),
        );
    }

    public function unescape($value)
    {
        return html_entity_decode($value);
    }
}
```

Add the following to your services.yml (or alternatively translate into xml).

```
 services:
     ha.twig.custom_extension:
     class: HA\SiteBundle\Twig\CustomExtension
     tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: This is elegant but in applications that are not communities or public facing web sites the 100% trust isn't really an issue :)

Comment: I agree, but it should still be a consideration, protecting the developer from themselves for example.

Answer (score 16):

Or https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html

```
{% autoescape false %}
   {{ your_item }}{# your_item won't be escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Drupal 8 and none of `raw` or `autoscape` works, this could happen because of the variable you're trying to print if it's a render array with a template holding a safe output (for example, a `hl2br` filter).

I that case, you would need to access the value through the render array and filter it, for instance:

```
{% autoescape false %}
  {{ item.content['#context']['value'] }}
{% endautoescape %}
```