# Twig truncate() and slice() return a string with html entity names

Tags: php, twig

I have a string with 69 characters:

```
This is a test with characters like € or "like this". How 'bout that?
```

I use CKEditor in my form and make the word 'test' bold. This is how it is saved it the database:

```
<p>This is a <strong>test </strong>with characters like &euro; or &quot;like this&quot;. How &#39;bout that?</p>
```

If I want to show the string without any markup I use the Twig-filters `striptags` and `raw` after each other which results in:

```
This is a test with characters like € or "like this". How 'bout that?
```

Now of the original string I want to show the first 65 characters without any styling. I use the Twig-filter `truncate (65)`. 
This is my code in Twig:

```
{{ string | striptags | raw | truncate (65) }}
```

My result is

```
This is a test with characters like &euro; or &quot;like this&quo...
```

As you can see the special characters are shown as their HTML entity name, even though I only added the `truncate` filter. Is this a bug or should this be expected? The same thing happens when I use the `slice` filter.

My result should be:

```
This is a test with characters like € or "like this". How 'bout
```

**EDIT:** I understand what the issue is now. When using the `raw` filter on a string this does not mean any of the original characters from that string (i.e. the HTML entity names) will not be counted when using `slice` or `truncate` filter. I still have not found a solution though.

Comment: @jeroen, they are there. They are saved in the database. I display the string in a Twig template, adding `raw` not to show the html entities.

Comment: And if you switch the order of `raw` and `truncate`? I think you need `raw` as the last filter.

Comment: @jeroen, my result will be a much shorter string then and also if the cut is made on a html entity the partial entity will show. `This is a test with characters like € or "like this&quo...` is the result.

Comment: The `truncate`-filter is not marked as safe, as seen in the [definition](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php). That means u'd need to apply `raw` twice e.g. `{{ string | striptags | raw | truncate (65) | raw }}`

Comment: @DarkBee, I tried that as well, results in `This is a test with characters like € or "like this&quo...`. Too short and with the cut html entity name.

Comment: [`striptags`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html) is mostly a wrapper around [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags), which couldn't care less about HTML entities.

Comment: I'm guessing you would first need to `html  decode` those entities yeah

Answer (score 0):

Create a twig function, which will converts the html entities to UTF-8 ( function has been defined in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453579/unescape-or-html-decode-in-twig-php-templating)).

```
class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('unescape', [$this, 'unescape']),
        ];
    }
    public function unescape($value)
    {
        return html_entity_decode($value);
    }
}
```

you can then use your function in your twig template:

```
{{ unescape(last_article.text  | striptags)  | slice(0,150) | raw  }}
```

the unescape convert your htmlentities to UTF-8, the slice will be performed afterwards