# js unescape twig encoded html content {{ myvar|escape('js') }}

Tags: javascript, twig

Hi i need convert html string and push to js var.

I convert it for JS in TWIG

```
$loadContent = '<html><.....' 


data-template-content="'{{ loadContent|escape('js')|raw }}'"
```

get somethink like that in Javascript/jquery $('body').attr('data-template-content')

```
title\u003E\n\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u003C\u0021\u002D\u002D\u005Bif\u0020\u0021mso\u005D\u003E\u003C\u0021\u002D\u002D\u003E\n\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u003Clink\u0020href\u003D\u0022https\u003A\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\/css\u003Ffamily\u003DLato\u0022\u0020rel\u003D\u0022stylesheet\u0022\u0020type\u003D\u0022text\/css\u0022\/\u003E\n\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u003C\u0021\u002D\u002D\u003C\u0021\u005Bendif\
```

How restore orginal content with js ?

i  try

```
unescape($('body').attr('data-template-content'))
```

or

```
JSON.parse($('body').attr('data-template-content'))
```

or

```
decodeHtmlEntities(value){
        let txt = document.createElement("textarea");
        txt.innerHTML = value;
        return txt.value;
    }
```

not work ..

"Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question" - (no this is other question) - how to escape in twig - this i know but how get original in JS this is question. I twig doc is no info about restore in JS,

use json_encode|raw ???

im in Javascript , i encode in twig and want get orginal in Javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unescape or html decode in Twig (PHP Templating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453579/unescape-or-html-decode-in-twig-php-templating)

Comment: use `json_encode|raw`

Comment: im in Javascript , i encode in twig and want get orginal in Javascript but is hard to find correct encode twig escape('js')

Comment: As I said, `{{ loadContent | json_encode | raw }}`

Comment: <body  data-template-content='{{ data|json_encode|raw }}' >
 console.log('data1', JSON.parse($('body').attr('data-template-content')));
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input, ok i use ajax load so no problems, content has 800kb

Comment: Do I understand this right, you've now switched to ajax and your problem is solved?

Comment: yes, thank You for helping.