# Compare to strings

Tags: twig

I have two string variables in twig that i can print properly like

```
{{ currpage }} , {{ field.value }}
```

But i can't compare them in an "if".
Tried `{% if (currpage == field.value) %}`, `{% if (currpage in field.value) %}`, `{% if (currpage same as field.value) %}` but the code after if is not executed.
However if i hardcode a value in the first part like `{% if ('blabla' in field.value) %}` it works.
How should i compare two variables in twig in opencart?

Comment: Did you try and dump both variables before comparing them?

Comment: yes, they 're both the same strings, i dumped them from php

Comment: Clearly they are not, if they were then this is not reproducible - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/s06qb2)

Comment: I found out in browser's source code page, that the second string shows the `&` as `&amp;`, so twig thinks they are different. How could i avoid it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unescape or html decode in Twig (PHP Templating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453579/unescape-or-html-decode-in-twig-php-templating)

Comment: No, but i replaced the & with &amp; using str_replace and it worked